# search for single character+space at beginning of string

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am searching for a single character at the start of of a sentence in excel.
E.g. suppose Cell A1 contains string "T code999"
A2 contains "WWW T 8"
A3 contains "TW"

WHen I search for the string "T " (T followed by space) then the result should only show cell A1 (where the string starts with T and there is a space after it)
Is there a way to search in excel like this?

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to find all instances of "T " (followed by a space) or all instances of " T " (has a space before and is followed by one)?

Comment: T followed by a space

Answer (score 7):

The most direct way to find the cells in column `A` is to set a filter on the column.

- Select any of the data cells in column `A` and then from the ribbon click on `Sort & Filter` / `Filter`. (This works  best if you have a header label in cell `A1`.)
- Click on the drop-down menu in cell `A1` and choose `Text Filter` / `Begins With`.

[image: Select Filter / Begins With]

- Enter "T *" where the cursor is (top, right-hand entry box) and press OK.
- Then simply highlight the filtered rows with colored fill, bold font, or whatever you choose.

[image: filtered rows with highlighting]

- Finally, remove the filter by clicking on the drop-down in cell A1 and selecting "Clear filter from ".

[image: highlighted rows that begin with <code>T</code> in column <code>A</code>.]

The key here is to add the asterisk, the wildcard character to match any series of characters,to the "begins with" filter string. If you try to filter using just "T ", Excel would truncate it to "T" and you would get all the cells that begin with T.

Note that the filter is not case-sensitive. If you need that, you would have to set up an advanced filter as described [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-HP005200178.aspx#BMcasesensitive).

Comment: +1 Bummer, I was looking for a way to look into multiple columns while all the data was in a single column ^^;

Answer (score 1):

I know that Excel's Find doesn't support Regex, otherwise I'd suggest that you use find on `^T` (there's a space after the T which gets ignored on posting...).

However, I think that you can achieve something similar to this by using Conditional formatting:

1. Click on cell A1 and select the whole sheet (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) or click on cell A then click on the intersection of columns and row labels to select everything.
2. Select Conditional Formatting, then New Rule.
3. Select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and in the input box "Format values where this formula is true", insert:

   ```
   =LEFT(A1,2)="T "
   ```

   `LEFT()` returns the first `n` characters from the beginning of a cell. Here, I have used `n=2`.
4. Click on the button "Format..." and choose a formatting. I like to use "Fill" and pick yellow, but it's up to you. Click "OK", and "OK" again. That should highlight the cells you are looking for.

**As per additional request**

I'm not sure what you are expecting exactly, but since you want all the rows, I would do it like this:

1. In a new column, let's say 'Z', concatenate all the cells with a unique delimiter. I think that `^` is a possible delimiter for this function. It will work if there are no `^` anywhere in your data. In row 2 for instance, you can have:

   ```
   =A2&"^"&B2&"^"&C2&"^"&D2&"^"&E2&"^"&F2...X2&"^"&Y2
   ```

   This will create a single long string.
2. In the next column, use:

   ```
   =IF(OR(LEFT(Z2,2)="T ",NOT(ISERROR(FIND("^T ",Z2)))),1,0)
   ```

   This will give `1` on all the rows that contain cells containing "T ".
3. Put a filter, and filter on all the `1` to get the rows you need.

**Pointed out by Barry Houdini (do not upvote me for this part), which is easier/simpler/shorter:**

1. In a new column, let's say 'Z', put the following formula and drag it down:

   ```
   =COUNTIF(A2:Y2, "T *")
   ```
2. Put a filter on column Z and filter out all the ones with `0`.
3. Highlight the rows you need.

Comment: I am testing your suggestion. It is highlighting specific cells which start with "T " Is there a way to highlight the entire row ?

Comment: @Goutam hmm, not that I know of, sorry :(

Comment: @Goutam I made up a workaround, hopefully that suits your need!

Comment: Note that LEFT is not case-sensitive while FIND **is** case-sensitive. If you don't care about case you can use COUNTIF like this `=COUNTIF(A2:Y2,"T *")>0`